# A bit stuck with the "triangle" program in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of an issue at the moment that I am hoping one of you can help me with. I have tried several things, and I just can't get it. I am trying to print a triangle of asterisks using JavaScript. The program is to ask the user for the amount of rows, and then the direction. I haven't even started with the direction yet because I can't get the rows to work. Odd thing is that I can get it to print out the triangle hard-coding the function call.

This is the JS file:

```
function myTriangle(){

var result = "";

var totalRows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
var direction = document.getElementById('UpOrDown').value;

for (var i = 1; i <= totalRows; i++){

    document.writeln("count");
for (var j = 1; j <= 1; j++)
    {
           result += "*";
    }

    result += "<br/>";
}
return result;
}

var answer = myTriangle();
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = answer;
```

This is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Lab 2</title>
<script src="scripts.js", "div.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Input Fields</legend>
    rows:      <input type="text" id="rows" /><br>
    direction: <input type="text" id="UpOrDown" /><br>
    press: <input type="button" value="GO!" id="myButton" 
    onclick="myTriangle();"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="myDiv">

</div>  

</body>
```

The output will be something like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: `var j = 1; j <= 1; j++)` is always going to iterate only once, is that intended?

Answer (score 2):

Generally there are four types of triangle  -

```
1.)*     2.) ***   3.)    *    4.) ***
   **        **          **         **
   ***       *          ***          *
```

Code for 1 -

```
var ast = [],
i, j = 4;
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
 ast[i] = new Array(i + 2).join("*");
 console.log(ast[i]);
}
```

Code for 2 -

```
var ast = [],
i, j = 4;
for (i = j-1; i >=0; i--) {
  ast[i] = new Array(i + 2).join("*");
  console.log(ast[i]);
}
```

Code for 3 -

```
var ast = [],
i, j = 4;
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
  ast[i] = new Array(j - i).join(' ') + new Array(i + 2).join("*");
  console.log(ast[i]);
}
```

Code for 4 -

```
var ast = [],
i, j = 4;
for (i = j-1; i >=0; i--) {
  ast[i] = new Array(j - i).join(' ') + new Array(i + 2).join("*");
  console.log(ast[i]);
}
```

To print asterisk in document rather than console -

```
 document.getElementById('anyElement').innerHTML+=ast[i] + '<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.writeln` will completely wipe the page unless it's called while the page is loading.

Therefore it will destroy `myDiv`, causing the `getElementById` to fail.

Furthermore, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with that `<script>` tag, but it looks like you need two of them.

EDIT: Oh, and this: `for (var j = 1; j <= 1; j++)` will only ever iterate once.

EDIT 2: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/jBWFN/) my implementation of a solution.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer this. I actually left that document.writeln statement in there by accident. I had tested this to see if it would pass the parameter in, and forgot to take it out before I posted this.....sorry about that.

However, I still can't get the line "for (var j=1; j<=1; j++).....or I should say my head around it. It works if I hard code the amount of rows into the function, so why not now?

Thanks again.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a JSFiddle link to my working solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks so much. This JSFiddle link is great......a lot of the time I do better when I try to "reverse engineer" a problem. I think I am a visual learner more than anything else.

Comment: Same here! That's how I learned. If anything about the Fiddle confuses you, I'll be happy to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a valid script tag.

```
<script src="scripts.js", "div.js"></script>
```

You need to break it up into two tags:

```
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<script src="div.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, it uses es2015 `.replace()` but there is a nice
polyfill for es5 as well [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Polyfill):

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');



function triangle (size) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    output.innerHTML += '*'.repeat(i) + '<br>';
  }
}

triangle(2);
```

This is a solution in ES3/5

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function triangle(size) {
  var allLines = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    var oneLine = createLine(i);
    allLines += oneLine;
  }
  return allLines;
}

function createLine(length) {
  var aLine = '';
  for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
    aLine += '*';
  }
  return aLine + "<br/>";
}

output.innerHTML += triangle(3);
```

```html
<div id='output'></div>
```